# Enabled Apache mod_status but server-status was not found on SUSE enterprise 11 SP1

Tags: sles, apache-2.2

In `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, I have remove the line of `Include mod_status` and add the following to the last line,

```
LoadModule status_module /usr/lib/apache2/mod_status.so
ExtendedStatus On

<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
AllowOverride None
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Location>
```

Then I restart Apache, and go to http://HOSTNAME/server-status, but I get the **page not found**, Did someone know why I get page not found?

Is there any more step needed to do to see the Apache status?

Thanks

Comment: * *Where* is this configuration placed ? I don't care what file, that's irrelevant.
* What does the **error log** say ?

Comment: This configuration placed at the last line of Apache httpd.conf file; Nothing related to mod_status in error log. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but now (on OpenSuSE 12.1) got the following to work (adding this to the end of httpd.conf; I haven't tried putting it in mod_status yet):

```
LoadModule status_module /usr/lib/apache2/mod_status.so
ExtendedStatus On
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
#  AllowOverride None
  Order Deny,Allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from all
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.200  192.168.1.202
</Location>
```

I would wonder if perhaps your "Deny from all" followed by "Allow from all" is causing your problem? To start with, try pubb